# Two domains and same configuration

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx server that redirects incoming calls to port 80 to 443 if the server name is sub1.mysite.com. Here's the config file:

```
server {
    listen                              80;
    server_name                         sub1.myite.com;
    return                              301 https://sub1.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                              443 ssl;
    include                             ssl-wedding.conf;
    server_name                         sub1.mysite.com;
    access_log                          logs/webapp.access.log;
    proxy_pass_header                   Server;
    root                                /var/www/nginx/wedding;
    index                               index.php;

    include                             vary_header.conf;
    include                             whitelist.conf;

    location /apiproxy/ {
        proxy_pass                      https://apidev.apisite.com/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files                       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass                    wedding_backend;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        try_files                       $uri $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param                   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        include                         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param                   REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param                   CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param                   CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
        fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
    }
}

upstream wedding_backend {
    server                              unix:/var/www/php/fpm-wedding.sock;
}
```

What I need to do is to accept calls also from sub2.mysite.com also redirecting any calls from 80 to 443 and using the same config of sub1. I figure 2 way of semi fixing this but are not quite compliant to what I need. One way is to change the first sever block to:

```
server {
    listen                              80;
    server_name                         sub1.myite.com sub2.mysite.com;
    return                              301 https://sub1.mysite.com$request_uri;
}
```

But that will change the url in the visitor's browser to sub1, i will like him to stay on sub2. Another way around is to duplicate block 1 and 2 using just server name of sub2, but is not quite maintainable since if I change something in one block i will have to change it in his copy too.

So, ideally what I want is the block 1 to just change the port and left the subdomain intact. And block 2 to handle the config, also will be useful for my app if I can add an http header depending if am I in sub1 or sub2, ex. X-SubDomainOrigin : "sub1".

Comment: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: Thanks you @AlexeyTen, any idea about the second part of the question? The custom http header.

Comment: `server_name  *.myite.com;` will catch all subdomains. And with previous comment will redirect to corresponding https server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do a 301 redirect to https for the domain provided by the client Host header:

`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.mysite.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}`